# Need help to stored form data into 2 different server

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i  m trying to develop one code .i want to stored the simple form data into 2  different server in their own mysql.

For example.
i have form Like Student data information related .
The form hosted on one server like  (A).and i want to stored form data on A server and as well i also want to stored another server .which is another like (B)

is it possible to do that.

thanks

Comment: do you have any sample code

Comment: no, but google does. We do not do your homework for you here, read on how to ask questions in the help center.

Comment: ok no worries thanks any way

Comment: BAD AND EASY SOLUTION:
you can open two connection with php with two different mysql servers and store data on both of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do MySQL Server Replication.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html

Comment: do you have any sample code to do this i m not sql developer .i just know little bit

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use multi-master replication. You should set replication from DB1 to DB2 and from DB2 to DB1. In that way you can store in two databases.